# Appending csv contents to an existing logstash index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I have a folder where a user will keep adding csv files for logstash to pick up. User will add csv files in this folder, on a daily basis. The csv files will have names like `yyyymmdd-dailyUsageData.csv`, i.e. the file name has the initial few characters as the date. The contents of the csv file will again have this Date value and some other columns i.e. Date, colA, colB, colC, and so on. The requirement is to load the contents of the csv files, on a daily basis, into logstash/elasticSearch, so as to create the visualisations in kibana.

Though I am able to do so for a single csv file, I am not sure how I can append the contents of the next day's csv file, which has a different timestamp in its name, to the index that has already been created. Below is a sample of the conf file that I created:

```
 input {
      file {
        path => "/etc/logstash/20160302-dailyUsageData.csv"
        type => "usageData"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/home/ec2-user/mysincedbfile"
      }
    }
    filter {
      csv {
          separator => ","
          columns => ["Date","colA", "colB"]
      }
      mutate {convert => ["colA", "integer"]}
      mutate {convert => ["colB", "float"]}
    }
    output {  
        elasticsearch {
            action => "index"
            hosts => "localhost:9200"
            index => "dailyUsage"
        workers => 1
        }
        stdout {}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `file` input can simply use [a pattern for the `path`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-path) instead of a single file

```
  file {
    path => "/etc/logstash/*.csv"
    type => "usageData"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/home/ec2-user/mysincedbfile"
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that works..Thanks..However, any changes to existing csv files do not reflect (in kibana)..Only appends i.e. insertion of new lines to existing csv files are taking effect. Any suggestions on how to make the appends work?

Comment: That's because of the sincedb file which keeps track of which lines have already been processed. You probably want to reprocess all lines on each change?

Comment: Yes, if I need to process all lines or only the changed lines, what is the way to do that?